# how to fix tinymce error "b.editor is null"

Tags: jquery, tinymce

i've got tinymce error **b.editor is null** from **tiny_mce_custom_popup.js**.

***b.editor is null** error* happens only in firefox. how to fix this?

to reproduce bug.

1. load page
2. reload page
3. error occur.

these are my html pages.

**test1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test TinyMCE</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="insert-media">
                <div class="insert-popup-button" title="insert media"></div>
                <div class="insert-popup-container">
                    <iframe name="media-browser" id="media-browser" src="media-popup.html" class="media-browser-dialog iframe-in-dialog"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                <div class="form-controls">Text input</div>
                <textarea name="body_value" placeholder="textarea input" rows="10" class="post-body"></textarea>
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
                <button type="reset">Reset</button>
            </form>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('.insert-popup-button').click(function() {
                    $('.insert-popup-container').toggle();
                });
            });


            $('.post-body').tinymce({
                // Location of TinyMCE script
                script_url : 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                apply_source_formatting : true,
                content_css : 'main.css',
                convert_urls : false,
                document_base_url : '/_vlab/test-tinymce/',
                inline_styles : true,
                preformatted : false,
                relative_urls : false,
                // fix bug when open and tinymce not show in first time.
                height: '400px',
                width: '100%'
            });// tinymce post-body


        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

**media-popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Media popup</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container media-container">
            <a href="#" onclick="return insert_media('<img src=\'001.jpg\'>');">insert media</a>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce_custom_popup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function insert_media( element ) {
                element = htmlspecialchars_decode( element, 'ENT_QUOTES' );
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, element);
                return false;
            }// insert_media


            function htmlspecialchars_decode (string, quote_style) {
                // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
                // +   original by: Mirek Slugen
                // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
                // +   bugfixed by: Mateusz "loonquawl" Zalega
                // +      input by: ReverseSyntax
                // +      input by: Slawomir Kaniecki
                // +      input by: Scott Cariss
                // +      input by: Francois
                // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
                // +    revised by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
                // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
                // +      input by: Ratheous
                // +      input by: Mailfaker (http://www.weedem.fr/)
                // +      reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
                // +    bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
                // *     example 1: htmlspecialchars_decode("<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>", 'ENT_NOQUOTES');
                // *     returns 1: '<p>this -> &quot;</p>'
                // *     example 2: htmlspecialchars_decode("&amp;quot;");
                // *     returns 2: '&quot;'
                var optTemp = 0,
                i = 0,
                noquotes = false;
                if (typeof quote_style === 'undefined') {
                    quote_style = 2;
                }
                string = string.toString().replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
                var OPTS = {
                    'ENT_NOQUOTES': 0,
                    'ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE': 1,
                    'ENT_HTML_QUOTE_DOUBLE': 2,
                    'ENT_COMPAT': 2,
                    'ENT_QUOTES': 3,
                    'ENT_IGNORE': 4
                };
                if (quote_style === 0) {
                    noquotes = true;
                }
                if (typeof quote_style !== 'number') { // Allow for a single string or an array of string flags
                    quote_style = [].concat(quote_style);
                    for (i = 0; i < quote_style.length; i++) {
                        // Resolve string input to bitwise e.g. 'PATHINFO_EXTENSION' becomes 4
                        if (OPTS[quote_style[i]] === 0) {
                            noquotes = true;
                        } else if (OPTS[quote_style[i]]) {
                            optTemp = optTemp | OPTS[quote_style[i]];
                        }
                    }
                    quote_style = optTemp;
                }
                if (quote_style & OPTS.ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE) {
                    string = string.replace(/&#0*39;/g, "'"); // PHP doesn't currently escape if more than one 0, but it should
                    // string = string.replace(/&apos;|&#x0*27;/g, "'"); // This would also be useful here, but not a part of PHP
                }
                if (!noquotes) {
                    string = string.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
                }
                // Put this in last place to avoid escape being double-decoded
                string = string.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

                return string;
            }// htmlspecialchars_decode
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

[jquery 1.9.0](http://jquery.com/)

[tinymce jQuery package 3.5.8](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php)

Comment: is there an online example available?

Comment: there is no online example sir.